# Javascript Date minus 30 minutes/Full Calendar Resize Wrong

Tags: javascript, css, date, yii, fullcalendar

I am using a javascript calendar which allows for the re-sizing of an event ie increase/decrease event duration. For some reason the event is giving me the end date plus 30 minutes. Therefore I need to minus 30 minutes from the result I am given. Currently the event resize works on steps of thirty minutes.

I managed to get the date, please see the object here:
[image]

I am not very familiar with Javascript and struggled to understand how to actually get the info considering `end` shows `W`, but in the end I am able to use `el.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:SS")`. See the end object:
[image]

Using `el.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:SS")` I need to minus 30 minutes from this. I have been able to achieve this using:

```
var datePart1 = el.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD H:");
var datePart2 = el.end.format(":SS");
var trueEnd = el.end.format("mm") == 30 ? datePart1 + "00" + datePart2 : datePart1 + "30" + datePart2;
```

This is not a clean way to do this though and if for example I changed the calendar to allow to 15 minute steps for the resize this solution would not work without modification. Can anyone tell me how I can use `el.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:SS")` and simply remove 30 minutes or if there is a cleaner way to do this without using format it would be much appreciated. Also if someone can tell me why `W` is displayed in the `end` parameter of the object and how to best deal with this it would really help for future.

Any other info I can give let me know.

**Important**

My original question tried to tackle the issue incorrectly. Although I would be able to fix the issue with the solution presented by Saransh, working code example:

```
var blah = new Date(el.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:SS"));
blah.setMinutes(blah.getMinutes()-30);
```

This was not a full solution. When resizing the event, the time shown on the event also was wrong by half an hour, therefore I would have to modify the library to minus half an hour both when submitting the change and also on the fly as you resized the event to change the time shown on the event itself. So pretty much change any instance of time calculation when dealing with the resize.

I placed the calendar on a separate page and included the bare minimum. Doing it this way, the resize performed as expected. I then went to original page and removed js/css files one by one. Eventually I saw that the bootstrap css file caused the issue by adding a few pixels to the cell size and therefore causing issues when calculating the time which uses the cell height. The line that caused the issue was

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Therefore at the very top of the PHP view file for the calendar I simply added:

```
<style>
    * {box-sizing: content-box;}
</style>
```

The cell heights are now as expected and the resize time calculation is working perfectly in all respects. I have had this issue as while ago, so certainly if you are using a calendar and including this in a project always check the CSS files to see if they are causing a conflict. Hopefully this will help someone in the future as I spent more time trying to figure out a hack than I did to actually resolve the issue in its entirety with a single line of css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date = new Date()
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes()-30)
```

will do what you want.

Comment: Although I do recommend seeing if you really want to subtract 30 minutes, date time can be a complex issue considering time zones for web applications, so you should use a more robust way like GMT time or some specific time zone

Comment: Surely this would use today's date and not the date I have?

Comment: I created a new date for example purpose, you can use the date you have instead, so el.end.setMinutes(el.end.getMinutes()-30) should do it assuming el.end is the javascript date

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I found the true cause to my issue and have solved this in another way (see the original question for the update), but certainly I was able to do what was originally requested using your method. Many thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat:- You could have posted that as an answer instead of editing and posting the answer in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `Date` constructor:

```
var myTime = new Date(myValue - 30* 60000);
```

Comment: I can use `new Date(myValue)` and get a date, however, using `new Date(myValue - 30* 60000)` when logging to the console I get `Invalid Date`